# Jupyter notebook command doesn't bring up Jupyter

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, pip

I am using windows 11
I installed Python latest version and installed pip also
I installed Jupyter using the command (at command prompt) "pip install jupyter"
Installation went fine.

When I try to launch Jupyter notebook using the command "jupyter notebook" it says "jupyter is not a recognzied internal or external command"

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Your Jupyter executable path is not added to the PATH environment variable

Answer (score 2):

In the start menu go to `environment variables` and select `Edit` the `system environment variables`. go to `Environment Variables`, find the `Path` variable then edit then go on new, add here your Jupyter installation, the default is C:\Users\your-username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PythonXX\Scripts replace with your actual userame then `OK` and start again your `jupyter notebook`

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have jupyter installed on your machine by:

```
pip install jupyter
```

Then try:

```
python3 -m jupyter notebook
```

or if you have other python version:

```
python -m jupyter notebook
```

Comment: The key point to note here is to install `jupyter` with the command `pip install jupyter`. I tried running Jupyter notebook after running `pip install jupyterlab`  and got this error. However, after running `pip install jupyter` the problem was resolved.